# Post data from a partial view to another action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, post

Just started with MVC and trying to do the following:

having a Details.cshtml with the following part on one of my tabs:

```
            <!-- DETAILS TAB CONTENT -->
        <div class="tab-pane profile active" id="details-tab">
            @if (ViewBag.ScreenMode == Constants.ScreenMode.View)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_ViewDetails", Model)
            }
            else
            {
                @*@Html.Partial("_EditDetails", Model)*@
                <div id="DetailsEdit">
                    @{Html.RenderPartial("_EditDetails");}
                </div>
            }
        </div>
```

My _ViewDetails.cshtml shows detail information and has the following to go to the Edit mode:

```
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Details", new { id = Model.EmployeeId, screenMode = Constants.ScreenMode.Edit })
```

When clicked, indeed the tab shows the contents of the partial view _EditDetails. My _EditDetails.cshtml looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeId)

        @* fields with editable controls. Left it out here *@

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

and having the following methods in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(Guid? id, Constants.ScreenMode? screenMode)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    Employee employee = employeeManager.Get(id.GetValueOrDefault());
    if (employee == null || employee.EmployeeId == null || employee.EmployeeId == Guid.Empty)
        return HttpNotFound();

    if (screenMode == null)
        screenMode = Constants.ScreenMode.View;

    ViewBag.ScreenMode = screenMode;
    return View(employee);
}


[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id, HttpPostedFileBase upload)
{
    // code here 

    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Employee", new { id = employeeToUpdate.EmployeeId, screenMode = Constants.ScreenMode.View });
}
```

However, when I press the save button from the edit partial view, it never hits my code Edit action in my controller. It only goes back to the Details action, which gets the info again. I thought by using the following at the beginning of my partial view, I could make the post go to my Edit action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Employee", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

What do I miss or are my thoughts completely wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are telling your ActionResult to go to the details view. Comment that line out and put code in to work the form entries.

Comment: After the edit action is done, it should go back to the details view, that's why I have the RedirectToAction. I have code in the Edit action with a breakpoint and it isn't executed. Left the code out here to get a more readable part.

Comment: Is that intended that you don't have a FormCollection parameter?

Comment: Thanks Kami, not complete sure what you mean. Instead of "Guid? id" using  "Employee employee"?

Comment: Just try the following:  public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection fc).

Comment: Sorry, no luck. However if I add a Details actions with "[HttpPost]", this one is executed. Somehow my definition at the BeginForm isn't picked up. The idea is that my details page will have several partial views and every partial view will have it's own HttpPost action.

Answer (score 0):

Aarghhhh, found it.

My Details.cshtml started with:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Employee", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Removed this and now it's working.
Overlooked this for days.

Thanks.